# How get isodate timestamp in JavaScript for MongoDb database

Tags: mongodb, mapreduce, mongoid

I am using the `mongoexport` tool to export data from a collection. My collection have `conn_time` field with `ISODate` timestamp. I want to export the data that was loaded in the last 15 mins.

I am using it like below but it returns error: `"Too many positions."`

```
-q '{conn_time:{$gt:"Fri' Sep 06 2013 22:23:20 GMT+0000 '(GMT)",$lt:"Fri' Sep 06 2013 22:38:20 GMT+0000 '(GMT)"}}'
```

The full command:

```
mongoexport --csv --out /tmp/aud_createcoll_log.csv 
--host abc.corp.ner:1089 
--db test --collection aud_create_log 
-q '{conn_time:{$gt:"Fri' Sep 06 2013 22:23:20 GMT+0000 '(GMT)",$lt:"Fri' Sep 06 2013 22:38:20 GMT+0000 '(GMT)"}}' 
--fields app_name,file_name,conn_time,conn_host,conn_command -u user -p 'aaaaaa' -v
```

Answer (score 0):

While I can't test your command line exactly (as I don't have your DB), I'd speculate there are a few issues:

1. Your query is using mismatched quotes. You've got an opening single quote (`'`), and then use a single quote several times in the query without escaping it in any way. So, the command line parser is getting very confused and misunderstanding that the remainder of the command line are additional arguments (too many in fact). You can use `\'` if you want to escape the single quotes, but as you'll see in the next suggestion, you shouldn't need the extra quotes anyway.
2. I'd suggest you use `ISODate` in the query, but you'll need to make sure it's in the correct format. For example: `ISODate("2013-09-07T20:03:38.739Z")`. As mentioned in the first point, this way, you won't need to use more than the double-quote to express the full date.

The command would look like this (as I said, I haven't tested it):

```
 mongoexport --csv --out /tmp/aud_createcoll_log.csv 
 --host abc.corp.ner:1089 
 --db test --collection aud_create_log 
 -q '{conn_time:{$gt:ISODate("2013-09-06T22:23:20"),$lt:ISODate("2013-09-06T22:38:20")}}' 
 --fields app_name,file_name,conn_time,conn_host,conn_command -u user -p 'aaaaaa' -v
```

Comment: when i used java script i got date in the format Fri' Sep 06 2013 22:23:20 GMT+0000 '(GMT) .but i want iso date to query data using mongo collections

Comment: @user2609099 - is that a question? Did my answer work for you?